# Problema para recuperar campos array[] adicionados dinâmicamente

Tags: php, jquery

Olá, pessoal!!

Tenho esse script que adiciona campos dinamicamente no meu form, mas não consigo percorrer os valores adicionados por ele, só consigo pegar o primeiro valor do campo que já vem na tela principal.... Segue o código do script:

```
$(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var input =  '<div class="dias">'
        input +=    '<div class="form-group dias">'
        input +=        '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Dia">Dia disponível</label>'
        input +=        '<div class="col-md-4">'
        input +=            '<select name="slcDia[]" class="form-control">'
        input +=                '<option value="Segunda">Segunda-Feira</option>'
        input +=                '<option value="Terça">Terça-Feira</option>'
        input +=                '<option value="Quarta">Quarta-Feira</option>'
        input +=                '<option value="Quinta">Quinta-Feira</option>'
        input +=                '<option value="Sexta">Sexta-Feria</option>'
        input +=                '<option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>'
        input +=            '</select>'
        input +=        '</div>'
        input +=        '<a href="#" id="deletar" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remover Dia</a>'

        input +=        '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Turno">Turno</label>'
        input +=        '<div class="col-md-4">'
        input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-0"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Manha">Manhã</label>'
        input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-1"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Tarde">Tarde</label>'
        input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-2"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Noite">Noite</label>'
        input +=        '</div>'
        input +=    '</div>'
        input += '</div>';

    $("#campos").append(input);
    return false;
});

$('body').on('click', "#deletar",function() {
    $(this).parent('.dias').remove();
});
```

Estou percorrendo os campos em php, é assim que estou fazendo:

```
        $slcDia = $_POST['slcDia'];

    foreach ($slcDia as $slcDia) {
        echo $slcDia;
    }
```

E o form principal, onde chama o script pra adição dos campos é esse, praticamente igual ao que tá dentro do próprio script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addcampo.js"></script>

    <form class="form-horizontal" action="index.php?pg=np&acao=ok" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Professores > Novo Professor</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Professores">Nome</label>  
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="txtNome" type="text" placeholder="Professor" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Dia">Dia disponível</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select name="slcDia[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Segunda-Feira">Segunda-Feira</option>
                    <option value="Terça-Feira">Terça-Feira</option>
                    <option value="Quarta-Feira">Quarta-Feira</option>
                    <option value="Quinta-Feira">Quinta-Feira</option>
                    <option value="Sexta-Feira">Sexta-Feria</option>
                    <option value="Sábado">Sábado</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <a href="#" id="add" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Adicionar Dia</a>

            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Turno">Turno</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-0"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Manhã">Manhã</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-1"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Tarde">Tarde</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-2"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Noite">Noite</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="campos"></div>

        <!-- Button (Double) -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Salvar"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <button type="submit" name="Salvar" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                <a href="index.php?pg=td" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Alguém sabe onde pode estar o erro?

Comment: Seu código parece correto para mim. Já tentou usar `print_r` ou `var_dump` para testar o conteúdo da variável que está sendo recebida?

Comment: `foreach ($slcDia as $slcDia) {` voce está a usar a mesma variável nos dois campos do `forEach`...

Comment: Cahe, já tentei sim, sempre vem só o primeiro valor, dos outros campos criados por último não recebo nada...

Sergio, estou usando a mesma variável de proposito aí, mas se eu usar foreach ($slcDia as $key => $value) dá a mesma coisa....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Os problemas:

Problema inicial: usar `$slcDias as $slcDia`

```
$slcDias = $_POST['slcDia'];

foreach ($slcDias as $slcDia) {
    echo $slcDia;
}
```

Mais um problema aqui: se a pessoa adicionar 3 campos novos, você vai ter 3 `id="deletar"`

```
<a href="#" id="deletar"...
```

Outro problema: com esse código vai ser uma confusão saber qual check é de quem:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Manha">Manhã</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Tarde">Tarde</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno[]" value="Noite">Noite</label>
```

O PHP só envia os checkbox que estão ON, então o índice deles pode variar bastante. Da forma que está, você não tem como saber qual checkbox é de qual dia. O ideal seria você criar um índice no JS para cada um dos blocos do `form` e passar para a aplicação num campo `hidden`.

### Solução possível:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var input =  '<div class="dias">'
    MeuIndice++; //crie essa variavel antes, na inicializacao
    ...
    input +=        '<div class="col-md-4">'
    input +=            '<input type="hidden" name="meuindice[]" value="'+MeuIndice+'">'
    input +=            '<select name="slcDia"'+MeuIndice+' class="form-control">'
    ...
    input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-0"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno'+MeuIndice+'[]" value="Manha">Manhã</label>'
    input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-1"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno'+MeuIndice+'[]" value="Tarde">Tarde</label>'
    input +=            '<label class="checkbox-inline" for="Turno-2"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno'+MeuIndice+'[]" value="Noite">Noite</label>'
    ...
```

Assim, para cada dia você vai ter um `meuindice[]` diferente, e nesse índice vai ter o valor pra dar um `$_POST['chkTurno'.$meuindice[i]]` para pegar os checkboxes só daquele dia. Este mesmo conceito pode ser aplicado ao `ID` do botão.

O PHP:

```
$meuindice = $_POST['meuindice'];

foreach ($meuindice as $i) {
   $slcDias = $_POST['slcDia'.$i];
   $checkboxes = $_POST['chkTurno'.$i];
   echo $slcDias;
   print_r( $checkboxes );
}
```

Não esqueça de atualizar o HTML original:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meuindice[]" value="0">
<select name="slcDia0" class="form-control">
...
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno0[]" value="Manhã">Manhã</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno0[]" value="Tarde">Tarde</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkTurno0[]" value="Noite">Noite</label>
```

Comment: ! Agora, com o código funcionando, entendi melhor o que você quis dizer!! Eu tava tentando encadear os foreach e pra cada dia eu teria o array com os turnos mas não deu, ele ta pegando todos os turnos selecionados pra cada dia, ou seja, se eu selecionei segunda à tarde e terça à noite, ele pega segunda tarde noite, terça tarde noite.... Como será q eu poderia resolver isso nesse caso?

Comment: @Alceu atualizei o código com um caminho para você solucionar o problema.

Comment: Pois é to tentando usa-lo aqui, mas agora não está mais funcionando a adição dos campos... =/